# Getting the pointer to dib in a bmp file in C++

Tags: c++

I want to get a byte * to the dib in a bmp file in C++. I know that bmp contains a bmp header and I need to open the bmp file and skip some bytes in order to get the pointer to the dib. I am unfamiliar with C++ so any code would be helpful!

Pseudocode of what I want to do:

```
byte * pointer = open(file.bmp);
pointer += number of bits to get to dib.
return pointer
```

Comment: Even if you get a pointer to the dib, are you sure you won't need StackOverflow to help you out again with bmp files, then again, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `seekg` to jump over the bmp header. I really recommend to read a tutorial about file IO, for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).